# Copying and pasting keyframes from a source camera to a destination camera (with no keyframes inside) remove all the keyframes from the source camera

Tags: camera, keyframes

I'm trying to copy all the keyframes from the camera 1 (**called camera**) to the camera 2 (**called voodoo_render_cam**) that's connected to an empty. What I do is : (in the dope sheet window) I select first all the keyframes of the camera 1 and then the camera 2 (it has no keyframes) and then I press **CTRL + L** and then "**animation data**" and happens that both the cameras have anymore keyframes embedded. All the keyframes are deleted. What's wrong ? what I'm trying to do ? I would like that the camera 1 (camera) disappear and that the camera 2 (voodoo_render_cam) take its place. It could also not disappear but I want that the camera 2 is placed on the same position of the camera 1. Maybe there is another way to do that. I have attached a [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R4e-8TW7O6rerOUIaFU2HPONw_dsgi8N) to show you what happens.

[image: a]

you can find the blender file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NiXgzJjs0fdrnZ84uSW_wFqt5foylLDL).

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is simply select the camera you want to copy the keyframes to, then select the other camera which has the desired animation, and hit ctrl-L and select Animation Data.  You have to select the camera with the desired animation LAST

Comment: I did also what you have suggested,but the camera is placed on the same position of the voodoo_camera. I don't want this. I want that the voodoo camera is placed on the same position of the camera and that its keyframes are still there. you can see what happens from this video : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R4e-8TW7O6rerOUIaFU2HPONw_dsgi8N

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you mean.  What should be happening from my answer is that the voodoo camera has the exact same animation as camera 1.  Is something else happening?

Comment: just making sure:  you are selecting camera one LAST, right?

Comment: I trid both the ways : selecting first the camera and selecting first the voodoo_camera. none worked as expected. can I give you the blender file ? do u want to give a look ?

Comment: I've added the blender file...

Comment: it works, select camera1, then camera2, then ctrl L > Animation Data, then the 2 cameras will take the exact same position because the position is part of the animations datas, then you can move the empty if you want to see camera2 somewhere else (your camera2 is parented to the empty)

Comment: Does that fix your problem?

Comment: it works only partially. the problem is that neither the camera 1 nor the camera 2 are able to stick on the coordinates (x=-7.0392 ; y = 0.044197 ; Z = 1.9601 ; rotation X = 81.7 ; rotation Y = 4.13 ; rotation Z = -121). when I move the keyframes,they come back to coordinates (x = 0 ; y = 0 ; z = 0 ; rotation x = 180 ; rotation y = 0 ; rotation Z = 0); instead at least one of the cameras should stick on the coordinates (x=-7.0392 ; y = 0.044197 ; Z = 1.9601 ; rotation X = 81.7 ; rotation Y = 4.13 ; rotation Z = -121) even if I play with the keyframes.

Comment: When I looked at your blender file, the camera actually labeled "camera"  had no animation for it.  Kinda hard to figure out the problem when there is no animation.  Am I just blind, or is there no animation?

Comment: no. the camera has no keyframes embedded. keyframes are on the voodoo_camera because it comes from the tracking process created by the voodoo tracker.

Comment: Could you explain the steps you've taken?  I am a ways behind the curb, I'm afraid.  Not sure what your exactly trying to accomplish with what you've got so far, and I don't know what steps you've been taking.